# formula for the area of parallelogram spanned by transformed vectors

Tags: matrices, vectors

Let $\vec v ,\vec w $ be vectors where $\vec v=v_1 \vec i +v_2 \vec j$ and $\vec w=w_1\vec i +w_2 \vec j $ and let $\underline A$ be a matrix.

Find the area of the parallelogram spanned by the transformed vectors $v_1\underline A \vec i+v_2 \underline A \vec j $ and $w_1\underline A \vec i + w_2 \underline A \vec j $.

The solution in my book is provided as :

$(v_1\underline A \vec i +v_2 \underline A \vec j ) \times (w_1 \underline A \vec i +w_2 \underline A \vec j )$

$(v_1w_2-w_1v_2)(\underline A \vec i \times \underline A \vec j )+v_1w_1(\underline A \vec i \times \underline A \vec i ) +v_2w_2(\underline A \vec j \times \underline A \vec j)$

But why is the coefficient of the fist term negative ?Why we  have $v_1 w_2-w_1v_2$ instead of $v_1w_2+w_1v_2$ ?

My feeling is that it comes from the cross product of $\vec v $ and $\vec w$ but formally I don't know how to prove it in the above equation.

Can you guys show me formally why we get a minus sign ?

Comment: Because $x \times y = -y \times x$ for any vectors $x,y$. (Here we have $x = \underline A \vec j$ and $y = \underline A \vec i$.)

Comment: $ -v_1w_2 \times \underline A \vec j +w_1v_2 \times \underline A \vec i $ ,that's what I get.

Comment: That makes no sense; $v_1w_2$ and $w_1v_2$ are scalars, not vectors.

Comment: I've figured out where my mistake was .